# Module import issue with a Japanese Tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, cjk

I am trying to get the JapaneseTokenizer working in python, but I am having trouble with one of the modules it depends on. Here is the trace of the errors I am getting:

```
/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/application/tokenizerTest.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/application/tokenizerTest.py", line 1, in <module>
        import JapaneseTokenizer
      File "/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/JapaneseTokenizer/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from JapaneseTokenizer.jumanpp_wrapper import JumanppWrapper
      File "/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/JapaneseTokenizer/jumanpp_wrapper/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .jumanpp_wrapper import JumanppWrapper
      File "/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/JapaneseTokenizer/jumanpp_wrapper/jumanpp_wrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
        from pyknp import Jumanpp
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Jumanpp' from 'pyknp' (/Users/home/PycharmProjects/SubLingo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyknp/__init__.py)
```

As you can see Jumanpp_wrapper is trying to import the module Jumanpp from pyknp. I have looked into the pyknp package currently installed on my machine and it does not have a module with this name. This leads me to conclude that the version of pyknp I have installed is not compatible with Jumanpp, so there must be another version available somewhere. The trouble is I install pyknp using the pip installer on my Mac, as recommended on the pyknp official site, so it should be the most current version. I'm not sure how to get an alternative version that contains the necessary module. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions for Juman++ at https://pypi.org/project/JapaneseTokenizer/?

Comment: Juman++ 1.02 is installed if that is what you mean, but I installed it with Brew rather than downloading the tar file and making the install myself.

Comment: In any case, as I said in the message, the issue appears to be that the current version of pyknp is missing the module "Jumanpp" which JapaneseTokenizer attempts to import. I just looked inside the current Juman module and it appears to refer to Jumanpp commands, so I am now wondering if the authors decided to combine the functionality from both Juman and Jumanpp into a single module.

Comment: I was speculating that Jumanpp itself contained a Python module, but this does not seem to be the case. Both packages are on Github, same author.

Comment: I have been in contact with the developer of JapaneseTokenizer. He agrees that the developers of pyknp have removed the Jumanpp module from their system for some reason. He will post an updated version of his tokenizer at some point. 
In the mean he gave a link to an version of pyknp: http://nlp.ist.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/DLcounter/lime.cgi?down=http://lotus.kuee.kyoto-u.ac.jp/nl-resource/pyknp/pyknp-0.3.tar.gz&name=pyknp-0.3.tar.gz. I am waiting on his permission to republish his full email response to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in direct contact with the developer of JapaneseTokenizer who has kindly given permission for me to repost his answer to my query:

I'm glad that you sent me a message about the issue. I read your post at StackOverflow. As other user suggested, the main issue is that pyknp package does not have juman++ module. I don't know the reason, but an author of pyknp package removed module for juman++.
The straightforward way to solve this issue is that you install pyknp package version 3 from here and install it your environment.
The main procedure is below.

1. remove pyknp package from your environment `pip uninstall pyknp`
2. get download pyknp package previous version. http://nlp.ist.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/DLcounter/lime.cgi?down=http://lotus.kuee.kyoto-u.ac.jp/nl-resource/pyknp/pyknp-0.3.tar.gz&name=pyknp-0.3.tar.gz
3. install the pyknp=0.3 with `pip install pyknp-0.3.tar.gz`

From now, I revise JapaneseTokenizer package. It might take some weeks. Next time you try to install JapaneseTokenizer package, everything will be fine.
Again, thanks for giving me a message.

Best,

Kensuke Mitsuzawa

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer of the package. I kindly thank you for using my package.

I fixed bugs related to the issues here and released newer package version 1.4.
https://github.com/Kensuke-Mitsuzawa/JapaneseTokenizers/releases/tag/1.4

You could install/upgrade the package with pip also.

Install `pip install JapaneseTokenizer` / Upgrade `pip install -U JapaneseTokenizer`